# Fastest way to locate a line which contains a specific word in a large text file

Tags: c#, file

I'm trying to locate a line which contains a specific text inside a large text file (18 MB), currently I'm using **StreamReader** to open the file and read it line by line checking if it contains the search string

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("search string"))
    {
        //Do something with line
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, because the file I'm using has more than 1 million records, this method is slow. What is the quickest way to achieve this?

Comment: As long as you don't have some sort of free text indexing in place, I think your best bet is to read the entire file into a memory buffer and perform a Boyer-Moore (or later derivatives) search on it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Reading the entire file into memory causes the application to hang and is very slow, do you think there are any other alternative?

Comment: http://lucenenet.apache.org/

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);` if that's what you mean? To import the whole file into memory?

Comment: If “causes application to hang” is a concern, you should consider multi threading. Because whatever method you use, I/O and search do take some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, disk IO of this nature is just going to be slow.  There is likely little you can do to improve over your current version in terms of performance, at least not without dramatically changing the format in which you store your data, or your hardware.

However, you could shorten the code and simplify it in terms of maintenance and readability:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filename).Where(l => l.Contains("search string"));
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    // Do something here with line
}
```

---

> Reading the entire file into memory causes the application to hang and is very slow, do you think there are any other alternative

If the main goal here is to prevent application hangs, you can do this in the background instead of in a UI thread.  If you make your method async, this can become:

```
while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("search string"))
    {
        //Do something with line
    }
}
```

This will likely make the total operation take longer, but not block your UI thread while the file access is occurring.

Comment: It is absolutely crazy how performant LINQ is compared to just a stream reader or buffered stream with stream reader methodology. I was getting close to 1 second on a 1.5 million line file using stream reader vs 5 milliseconds using the LINQ methodology. And it's much easier to read!

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a hard drive with a faster read speed (moving to a solid state drive if you aren't already would likely help a lot).
2. Store the data across several files each on different *physical* drives.  Search through those drives in parallel.
3. Use a RAID0 hard drive configuration.  (This is sort of a special case of the previous approach.)
4. Create an index of the lines in the file that you can use to search for specific words. (Creating the index will be a lot more expensive than a single search, and will require a lot of disk space, but it will allow subsequent searches at *much* faster speeds.)

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to say, I was only interested in knowing if there's a better approach to what I'm trying to do. If you are trying to point out to hardware upgrades then that won't work; because the application will be used by other people in the future as well, not just me, so I surely won't force them to upgrade in order to use my application...

Comment: @GiovanniMounir Well, these are the types of things you'd need to do to *actually* speed anything up.  The other answer isn't actually speeding up anything in the application at all, it's just providing more succinct code to do the same thing.  Changing *just* the code and nothing else is unlikely to result in any noticeable performance differences.  Your bottleneck is simply the ability of the hard drive to read the data from the file into memory.